# Deep RL loss function

Tags: reinforcement-learning

How is Deep Q-learning loss function defined? What I can't understand is that every time we are in a state and we select an action based on a policy derived by Deep Q-network only one of the Q values is considered , which means that instead of a vector we have an Scalar. In other words the loss function only consists of one term. Am I correct? The notations used in papers is ambiguous.